# Draw a picture in LaTeX

Tags: diagrams

Please help me to draw the following picture in LaTeX:

[image]

Thank you for all kind

Comment: What have you tried? You could try TiKZ, or pstricks, or asymptote, or metapost, or includegraphics using a drawing you produce in a drawing package. Or you could write in capital letters in your tex file INCLUDE PICTURE 1 HERE, and then draw the picture by hand, and ask your publisher to put in a suitable illustration there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should get you started (or use [Hugos answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/226259/828), to which he beat me by some minutes).

I didn't want to look up the intersection code, since generally, "draw this for me" questions without any work at all are not the best questions to be asked here on tex.SE.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) node [anchor=south east] {\(w\)} -- (1,0) node [anchor=south] {\(u\)} -- (0,-2) node [anchor=north] {\(v\)} -- cycle;
    \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) node [anchor=west] {\(u_{s}\)} -- (0,-1) node [anchor=east] {\(v_{s}\)} -- cycle;
    \draw (0.6,-0.6) node [anchor=north west] {\(tu+(1-t)v\)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve it by using the *tikz* package. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (W) at (-2,-6);
    \coordinate (Vs) at (-1,-3);
    \coordinate (V) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (U) at (5,0);
    \coordinate (Us) at (9,0);

    \draw (W) node[left]{v} -- (Vs) node[left]{$v_s$} -- (V) node[above]{w} -- (U) node[above]{u} -- (Us) node[above]{$u_s$};

    \draw[name path=seg1] (5,0) -- (-2,-6);
    \draw[name path=seg2] (-1,-3) -- (9,0);

    \path [name intersections={of = seg1 and seg2}];
    \coordinate (I)  at (intersection-1);

    \draw (I) node[below, right]{tu+(1-t)v}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can change the coordinates of the points if you need to. Just change the first lines to the appropriate coordinates.

Comment: You could merge the three last lines to `\node[name intersections={of = seg1 and seg2},below right] at (intersection-1) {$tu+(1-t)v$};`

Comment: In addition, try to avoid using [the minimal class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114/13304).

Answer (score 3):

Two other candidates: [MetaPost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) and [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net), both drawing programs closely related to (La)TeX. One may prefer such solutions since they are (contrary to TeX, LaTeX and cie) full-fledged programming languages, and thus sometimes easier to handle.

With MetaPost:

```
input latexmp; setupLaTeXMP(textextlabel = enable, mode = rerun);
numeric u; u = cm ; pair W, Vs, V, U, Us, I ;
V = u*(-2, -6); Vs = u*(-1, -3); W = origin; U = (5u, 0); Us = (9u, 0);
I = whatever[V, U] = whatever[Vs, Us]; % The intersection
beginfig(1);
  draw U -- V -- W -- Us -- Vs;
  label.top("$w$", W); label.top("$u$", U); label.rt("$u_s$", Us);
  label.lft("$v_s$", Vs); label.lft("$v$", V); 
  label.lrt("$tu+(1-t)v$", I);
endfig;
end.
```

To be compiled with LaTeX as TeX engine. In the command line, it needs something like this: `mpost --tex = latex mypic.mp`, or `mptopdf --tex=latex mypic.mp` if you prefer direct PDF output.

Result:

[image]

The same picture with Asymptote now:

```
settings.outformat="pdf";
unitsize(1cm);
pair v = (-2, -6), vs = (-1, -3), w = (0, 0), u = (5, 0), us = (9, 0);
pair I = intersectionpoint(v -- u, vs -- us); // The intersection
draw (u -- v -- w -- us -- vs);
label("$w$", w, N); label("$u$", u, N); label("$u_s$", us, E);
label("$v_s$", vs, W); label("$v$", v, W); 
label("$tu+(1-t)v$", I, SE);
```

To be compiled (in a Terminal) with an instruction like this: `asy mypic.asy`

The result:

[image]

Note that with both programs the intersection point is easily and automatically computed.